# Wrapping SOAP web service in JSON REST service

Tags: json, web-services, rest, soap, web

I was wondering if I could pick your brains. We've a legacy SOAP web service which we need to call upon to supply our application with some data. Our calling application is a JSON/Rest service (built using Java, Spring, Angular). We'd like to wrap the legacy SOAP service in a JSON service but in doing this of course we'd need to handle ourselves the boilerplate stuff like marshalling/unmarshalling, dealing with exceptions etc. While this isn't the toughest thing to do I was wondering are the any opensource alternatives which "wrap a soap service in a json/rest service" ? - i.e. like the following:
https://strongloop.com/strongblog/soap-into-rest-apis-with-loopback-node-js/

Any thoughts/guidance on this would be great.

Many thanks - Ro.

Comment: Doesn't than loopback thing do just what you ask?

Comment: Hi, yes it does but I just wanted to check if there are any other alternatives too. One of my colleagues had looked at it and thought it was a little messy to use. So I thought I'd put up a general question to see if there are more, while I'm investigating it all :-)